# Why am I getting FileNotFoundException when hitting a URL to fetch content?

Tags: java, exception

I have method here, where I am passing a url, username, and password in my method.

Here is my method:

```
private void fetchURL (String urlString,String user,String pass) {  

try {
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConn;
    DataOutputStream printout;
    DataInputStream input;

    Properties sysProperties = System.getProperties();

    sysProperties.put("proxyHost", "proxy.cyberway.com.sg");
    sysProperties.put("proxyPort", "8080");
    sysProperties.put("proxySet", "true");
    url = new URL (urlString);
    urlConn = url.openConnection();
    urlConn.setDoInput (true);

    urlConn.setDoOutput (true);

    urlConn.setUseCaches (false);

    urlConn.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream ());

    String content = "USERNAME=" + URLEncoder.encode (user) + "&PASSWORD=" + URLEncoder.encode (pass);

    printout.writeBytes (content);
    printout.flush ();
    printout.close ();

    input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream ());
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("D://outcome.txt");
    String str;
while (null != ((str = input.readLine())))
{

    if (str.length() >0)
    {
        fos.write(str.getBytes());
        fos.write(new String("\n").getBytes());
    }
}
    input.close ();
}
    catch(MalformedURLException mue){ System.out.println (mue);}
    catch(IOException ioe){ System.out.println (ioe);}
}
```

What I am getting is this exception:  java.io.FileNotFoundException:  URL/Address

Why am I getting this error? And what is the issue?

Comment: please post your stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It's either D:\\ or D:/

Not D:// because the :// is a sequence used for protocols such as http:// or file://

Comment: There error is still there. java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: I see. Which line do you say it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Use java File class in the FileOutputStream as,

```
File file = new File("D:\\outcome.txt");
if (!file.isExists) {
  file.createNewFile();
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
String str;
while (null != ((str = input.readLine()))) {

    if (str.length() > 0) {
       fos.write(str.getBytes());
       fos.write(new String("\n").getBytes());
    }
}
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29) says that, the FileOutputStream will throw FileNotFoundException if the file doesnot exists and the stream cannot create new file.

So the better way is to use File object in FileOutputStream

Comment: Good suggestion. But the error is still there. java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL/Address

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman I have edited my answer by checking for presence of file and create a new file if file is not present.